# Having trouble in understanding FOL structure

Tags: first-order-logic

Let $L$ be the language {$c,d,f,g,R$}.
Given c,d are constant symbols. f,g are function symbols. R is relation symbol.

$N$={$\mathbb{N}$,0,1,+,·$\leq$}, in this structure, the formula ($\forall$ x)(c $\leq$ x $\land$ ($\neg$ c = x $\to$ d $\leq$ x)) expresses that every element is "non-negative" (i.e. at least 0) and that if an element is strictly positive, it greater or equal to 1.

I don't understand the second half, "if an element is strictly positive, it greater or equal to 1."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *interpretation* of the language $L$ with the *structure* $N$ maps :

- the *constant* symbol $c$ on the number $0$,
- the *constant* symbol $d$ on the number $1$,
- the (binary) *function* symbols $f$ and $g$ on the operations of addition ($+$) and multiplication ($\times$) respectively,
- the (binary) *relation* symbol $R$ on the relation $\le$.

Thus, we have to compare the original formula :

> $(∀ x)(R(c,x) ∧ (¬(c = x) → R(d,x)))$

and its interpretation in the said structure :

> $(∀ x)(0 ≤ x ∧ (0 \ne x → 1 ≤ x))$.

With this interpretation, the formula means :

> > for all natural number $n$, $n$ is non-negative and if it is not zero then it is greater-or-equal to one,

that "sounds good" : every natural number is greater-or-equal to zero and if it is not zero (and thus it is positive) then it is greater-or-equal to one.

Comment: c must be 0 and d must be 1? I thought c and d can be either 0 and 1. The interpretation you give is (∀x)((0≤x∧0≠x)→1≤x). But in the question it looks like (∀x)((0≤x∧(0≠x→1≤x)).

Comment: @yashirq - YES. The "rule" is that we have to map the symbols of the language $\{ c,d,f,g,R \}$ on the "mathematical objects" of the *structure* $\{ 0,1,+,\times, \le \}$ ("leaving aside" the domain $\mathbb N$ that interpret the quantifiers. Of course, the arity of the symbols must be the correct ones (e.g. the binary predicate symbol $R$ must be mapped on a binary *relation*).

Comment: Then it makes sense. I get it. Thank you.

Comment: @yashirq - restored the original parentheses...